# How do I publish specific files not in project in VS 2010?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way I can publish *.ascx files without adding them to my project?

I am trying to make my user controls in Visual Studio 2010 reusable. I have a project containing my user controls called ControlsLibrary solution directory. I copy the ascx files to the web directory upon building the project with build events.
I use the command `copy "$(SolutionDir)ControlLibrary\*.ascx" "$(ProjectDir)controls\"`

This copies the *.ascx files from G:/SolutionDirectory/ControlsLibrary to C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/WebProject/controls

Now when I publish WebProject, the publish does not copy the *.ascx files from C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/WebProject/controls to my website. This is because they are not added to my project.

Is there a way I can publish *.ascx files without adding them to my project?

I know there is a way to publish all files by selecting the option "All files in this project."  That includes more files than I want.

Comment: Is what I am asking impossible? What is an alternate solution? The reason I do not want to add the files to the project is because Then I will have 2 copies of the same file and I do not want people to get confused about which is which.

Comment: This is the tutorial I followed to make the code reusable. But it is also the root cause of this question: http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/UserControls.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using the Virtual Path Provider approach?  Here's a good article on it:  [Load Web Forms and User Controls from Embedded Resources](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx).